# innerHTML is working on body element but not p element

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I want to a display a message on the screen that says "Please enter a valid email address" if the email address is not valid. The innerHTML statement for the body element is working fine but the one I'm using for the p element doesn't work.

One time when I was testing it, I saw the message "Please enter a valid email address" display and then after I clicked the ok button for the "not valid" alert box the message went away.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
function validateEmail() {
    var emailRule =  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;   
    if (emailRule.test(document.forms[0].email.value)) {
       document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "Thank you for signing up for our newsletter! You will recieve a confirmation email shortly.";
       setTimeout("window.close()", 3000);
    }
    else
       window.alert("not valid");       //for debugging
       document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
}  
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
</head>
<body id="body">
<p>If you sign up for our newsletter you will be entered into a drawing to win free clothes every month!</p>
<br>
<p id="message"> </p>
<form action="" onsubmit="validateEmail();">
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="Sign up"/></p>
<br>
<input type="button" value="No thanks" onclick="window.close()"/>
<br>
</form>
<p><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know `else` doesn't care about indentation, only curly braces `{}`?

Comment: Good point. I'll try that. Then again I only added the window.alert statement because I had this problem, so I think the problem will still be there.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias `if` and `else` work fine without `{ }` when there's only one line in its body

Comment: @Ian he have to clause after the else, so the second line will always be runned. Yeah I know that wasn't related to the issue, that's why it's a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is submitting no mather what because you don't prevent the default action. That's why the message appear (working) and disappear (page reload)

```
function validateEmail(e) {
    if( valid ) { /* stuff */ }
    else {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    /* etc */
```

Comment: This could work, but keep in mind that this is being done at the beginning of the function, so if the validation is successful the form will have to be submitted manually.

Answer (score 1):

[**Working jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/TPa66/1/)

---

Firstly, add braces to your else statement if you're going to keep the console.log - it can work without them, but only for one line after is affected, whereas you have two lines after, so the innerHTML with be changed regardless of the if/else.

Also, add Javascript's **[event.preventDefault()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)** to stop the form from submitting if the else statement occurs:

```
else {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function validateEmail() {
    var emailRule =  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (emailRule.test(document.forms[0].email.value)) {
         document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "Thank you for signing up for our newsletter! You will recieve a confirmation email shortly.";
         setTimeout("window.close()", 3000);
    }
    else
    {
         window.alert("not valid");       //for debugging
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
    }
}

</script>

</head>
<body id="body">
<p>If you sign up for our newsletter you will be entered into a drawing to win free clothes every month!</p>
<br>
<p id="message"></p>
<form action="" onsubmit="validateEmail();">
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="Sign up"/></p>
<br>
<input type="button" value="No thanks" onclick="window.close()"/>
<br>
</form>
<p><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That gives me "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

Answer (score 0):

The form is submitting regardless of the result of the statement. The code is working, but the page is being reloaded by the form submit. Adding `return false;` fixes the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function validateEmail() {
    var emailRule =  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (emailRule.test(document.forms[0].email.value)) {
         document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "Thank you for signing up for our newsletter! You will recieve a confirmation email shortly.";
         setTimeout("window.close()", 3000);
    }
    else
         window.alert("not valid");       //for debugging
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
         return false; // this stops the form from submitting, and the page from reloading.
}

</script>

</head>
<body id="body">
<p>If you sign up for our newsletter you will be entered into a drawing to win free clothes every month!</p>
<br>
<p id="message"> </p>
<form action="" onsubmit="validateEmail();">
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="Sign up"/></p>
<br>
<input type="button" value="No thanks" onclick="window.close()"/>
<br>
</form>
<p><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```